# Find CFG for Lisp-like expressions

Tags: context-free-grammar

All Lisp-like expressions.

A Lisp expression may be an unsigned integer or a list. A 
list, enclosed by left and right parentheses, consists of one operator ($+$, $-$, $*$, $/$, $\max$, 
$\min$) followed by a sequence of at least one Lisp expression. For instance, $13$, $(- \;8)$, 
$(*\; 9\; 3)$, $(+\; (*\; 2\; 2)\; 4)$, and $(\min\; (\max\; 3\; 1\; 4) (\max\; 2\; 7\; 1))$ are Lisp expressions.

This is my solution:

\begin{gather}
S \to X \mid Y \\
X \to 0\text{–}9 X \mid \epsilon \\
Y \to ( E )\mid \epsilon \\
E \to +,-,*,/,\max,\min YX
\end{gather}

Comment: The computer science stack exchange may get you better results.  There are two of them:  
http://cs.stackexchange.com/  and 
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmm.. so X is your unsigned integer and Y is your list?  Don't forget any lisp expression can be used as arguments of an operation (see your min/max example, for instance).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the term is "S-expression".  No?